# Unreachable code error in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate, findviewbyid

Getting Unreachable code error, not sure why. Any help would be awesome, only beginner.
Getting it on 3rd line of code final View thumb1View = getView().findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);

Code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zoom, container, false);


        final View thumb1View = getView().findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
        thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });

        final View thumb2View = getView().findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_2);
        thumb2View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb2View, R.drawable.image2);
            }


        });

        // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        return thumb2View;

    }
```

Comment: No sorry, only a beginner. Sorry :S

Comment: @ZazGmy, your comment didn't help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to write this method is like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zoom, container, false);


    final View thumb1View = view.findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });

    final View thumb2View = view.findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_2);
    thumb2View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb2View, R.drawable.image2);
        }


    });

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    return view;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for being such a noob. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

Since you are calling a return before the third line you get the error specified.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zoom, container, false);
```

Comment: So should I move that line down under it?

Comment: Remove that return it and it will work, you. are returning the view a  few lines below. I recommend you to learn the java and Android basics you can find a lot in Google and here.